# Why can't I post something on Physics Exchange for 2 days?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

Why can't I do it? It's stupid, I want to ask more questions!
And why can't it be for only about 4 hours?

Comment: Your tone isn't helping your case. I suggest you approach such matters in a more civil way in the future. You'll find that the payoff is worth it.

Comment: What a strange question...  I'm with @ToddMinehardt here.

Comment: Beware, deleting the posts actually avoids others to vote up them. To get out, probably requires upvotes. Don't delete them, try to fix them. The SE doesn't say the exact details of the q/a ban, and also not under what circumstances can you get out. My impression is that the real danger is not so hard as it seems on the first spot, and I suspect it may be also time limited. But nobody knows for sure. Try to fix your posts and be patient.

Comment: Probably a few upvote is already enough, and it doesn't matter if the not deleted posts get further downs meanwhile. If you already deleted posts, undelete them (you can get their list on the "deleted recent questions/answers" link on your user page). If you edit your post, it will bring it to the top on the main site page, thus it will get votes with a higher chance (between them also ups, if your fixes were okay).

Answer (score 17):

There are a set of automated quality control policies active on the site that set temporary (and no-so-temporary) bans on posting.

These bans are specific to either questions or answers and are triggered when a user has too many recently closed, deleted, or down-voted posts of the same kind (question or answer). They are sometimes called the 'q-ban' (for questions) or 'a-ban' (for answers)

To get them to go away you need to *improve* your existing posts so that users will up-vote them (or at least rescind down-votes). I see that you deleted a number of your own posts, but I am afraid that won't help with the q-ban.

You can, of course, simply wait it out but you should be aware that when you come off such a ban the system will still know about those previous posts and will be near threshold for re-instituting the ban, so make sure that you provide *good* content afterward lest the system pounce again.

Comment: It's also important to note that the (q/a)-ban system is sensitive not just to accounts but also to IPs, so trying to ask from a new account is liable to make things worse.

Answer (score 15):

This is the message you're shown when you try to ask a question. I'm quoting it in its entirety in the hope that you read it this time:

> **It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!** 
>
> You've asked 4 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely. 
>
> It's been 1 day since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 2 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit [your previous questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions), editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments. 
>
> **Recommended reading:** 
>
> - [tips on asking great questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as our guidance on 
> - [which questions are allowed here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
>
> **Additional advice** 
>
> - Examining highly-scored questions in the tags that interest you is a great way to study how to ask better questions, that also get better answers much sooner! 
> - We don’t demand perfection, but ***please* make sure you use proper grammar, spelling and capitalization**, it really helps! 
> - Improve downvoted questions rather than deleting them. 
> - Do not delete your account, create new accounts, or otherwise attempt to circumvent these restrictions. 
> - Do not contact us regarding these restrictions, they cannot be lifted. 
>
> Failure to heed this advice may increase the severity of these restrictions. 
>
> **For more information** 
>
> See: [Why won’t the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days/271543#271543) 
>
> It sometimes takes a few attempts at a good question in order to fully learn how our system works, and what the community expects from folks seeking answers. Just **do your best** to make sure you've improved the quality of your existing questions, and we'll see you in 2 days!