# Will I still get banned?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban, quality

I have 2 questions with one upvote, 3 ques with 2 upvotes and other one with 2 downvotes. Will I get banned if a question I post next is of low quality?

P.S.: I got banned yesterday but the ban was lifted after my 2 questions got an upvote.

Comment: Use your lifted ban carefully.

Answer (score 5):

There are different restrictions that may be imposed upon you, partly based on the performance of your previous posts:

1. **General rate limiting:** Users below 125 reputation can often only ask one question every 40 minutes network-wide, cf. [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/263383).
2. **Low-quality rate limiting:** If your questions or answers are poorly received, a [rolling rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/263383) ranging anywhere from 1 to 7 days may be imposed.
3. **Anti-recidivism rate limiting:** If you deleted your account and created a new one, you may find yourself only being able to post a single question per week, cf. [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/263383).
4. **Comprehensive question ban**: This is the most severe automatic restriction, [recently enabled on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/263383). If you have posted a significant amount of poorly received posts, the system will ban you *permanently* from posting until these are improved.

We can neither tell you whether you will be restricted from posting if your next contribution will be poorly received nor for how long because the algorithms that determine this are *intentionally* not public to avoid malicious users gaming them. However, the system will usually *warn* you that your last posts were poorly received before imposing a rate limit, and the permanent ban will only kick in after several such warnings and increasingly severe rate limits. If you follow the guidelines you are shown when a rate limit is imposed (shown by Shog9 in [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9647/50583)), you should not be in danger of getting to that point.

Comment: Important note: this answer (v1) describes *automatic* restrictions on participation, based on the quality of your questions and answers over time. These automatic restrictions are completely independent of the [timed suspensions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) which may be manually imposed by the [site moderators](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

Comment: **Comprehensive question ban**: This is the most severe automatic restriction, recently enabled on all sites. If you have posted a significant amount of poorly received posts, the system will ban you permanently from posting until these are improved, but if these posts can't be improved then what shall I do then?

Comment: @ErezZrihen See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/263383