# Unclear What You're Asking

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, close-reasons

I recently posted a question closely related to (but not identical to) this one.  I promise not to continue posting  variants.

That said:  I have just voted to close [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/331004/opening-a-portal-between-earth-and-outer-space) as "unclear what you're asking", because it's entirely unclear what the OP is asking.

However, in casting that vote, I am also automatically inviting  this poster to "please clarify your specific problem or add additional details".  I do not actually want this poster to clarify the problem or add additional details, and I wish I could cast this close vote, for this reason, without having to issue that invitation.  Ought the phrase "Unclear what you're asking", unadorned, be made available as a reason for closing?

Comment: I feel the latter portion of [my answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9801/50583) to your previous question would apply equally well here.

Comment: Subjective viewpoint: most people who post weird questions like that tend not to come back and adjust it for reopening.

Comment: I think it ended up being closed with the right choice -- not mainstream physics -- and I wouldn't have used the "unclear what you're asking" vote. I reserve unclear for "improvements could be made to make this okay" and "not mainstream" for things spouting utter gibberish, like that one.