# Why am I blocked from posting further questions?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

As all community members know I am just a beginner of physics. Mistakes often happens from everyone. Why can't everyone give me a second chance to blot out my mistakes and this is how I can improve my knowledge in physics. So I request community members to withdraw my ban.

Comment: could you be a little clearer about what "ban" you mean? Are you blocked from posting questions and/or answers? Have you been suspended from chat? Something else?

Comment: Is there any message explaining it?  You should have gotten some sort of notification explaining why and exactly what has happened.  Once you know the wording, look it up here, because it’s probably been asked already.

Comment: @nitsua60 I am banned from asking question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are currently blocked from posting further questions by the automatic question rate limiting, whose different forms I also discuss in [this answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9699/50583). There is nothing any user or moderator on this site can do to ameliorate this ban, it is a fully automatic consequence of your bad question record:

Of your 10 questions, none has a positive score, only one does not have a *negative* score, only one is not closed, and five are deleted. The question rate limiting is the system telling you to take seriously the feedback you are getting.

On the page that tells you you cannot post further questions you should see a link to [this help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited), which gives generic tips for how to improve your questions.

Comment: To reiterate: take seriously the feedback you are getting. The restrictions you're getting now are indications by the system that if you get further feedback along a similar vein (i.e. you ask questions that are downvoted (because you don't work on them enough) or closed (because you ask off-topic questions)) then the restrictions will get stricter.