# My posts downvoted

Tags: discussion, support

I am autistic. It's easy for the physics Stack  Exchange team to say I need to amend, so I'm learning as I go.

One criticism was that a poster couldn't understand a question. I showed them the question in a different way and they didn't reply back when I asked if that cleared it up.

Another poster said, why post something so long? I replied, it's kind and shows effort to show understanding, besides, I've posted short posts before and been accused that it was too short. When is something too warm, too cold but just quite right?

Another poster said I was wrong to post the entirety of my question on two pages, except after a threshold the system reported it could detect emspelling errors, and typing slowed down as a result. Catch 22?

As a result, I assumed that I had to split it into two posts as I didn't think it would post it. I thought that wasn't a bad assumption.

Now I've been banned from posting for an *undisclosed* time? Further, I've noticed a repeating characteristic behaviour. Instead of asking concerning content in a post, and waiting for a reply they downvote immediately, not giving me a proper chance to explain.

I am autistic, and I suffer badly from this kind of behaviour. At least please have the decency to let someone explain. Why are players here so gung-ho to just downvote? One moderator the other day couldn't understand why a variation in g_00 led to a metric non-conservation. I went on to say because any variation must lead to a change, where g_00 is the correct mathematical language to express the energy of a vacuum. So he downvoted me because of his own ignorance!

Comment: The notion that people should have to explain their downvotes has been discussed since the beginnings of SE, see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/50583 and its linked questions.

Comment: Aye I have learned the error of my understanding and ways, the moderator argued with me on g_00 and voted to close my account. I might be making mistakes, but the decision to do that seems unfair. It seems that this is a censorship support based on popularity rather than than any science being wrong from my behalf. Is there any way to appeal? @ACuriousMind

Comment: I’m sorry there must be a misunderstanding: nobody votes to close *accounts*. Maybe you can also link to the appropriate question in your post: superficially none of your questions have been closed.  I do not see any bans either (possibly already over).

Comment: I can't find it @ZeroTheHero. I assume it was deleted?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Remember that you cannot see deleted posts in the question/answer lists of the accounts of other users. | OP: The restriction you are currently under is automatic, not manually imposed by any moderator, see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9699/50583, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10639/50583 and their linked questions. It is strange that you have to *assume* the posts you are talking about were deleted because you deleted them yourself (e.g. [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/731911/50583))

Comment: The title included, why the hype of a logarithmic evolution? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: I honestly don't recall deleting that thread. In fact, I was in the process of taking what I wrote in the second post by copy paste and just as it was submitted, it was gone... did I delete it? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: Apparently I have. I am so sorry. @ZeroTheHero

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732030/the-recent-hype-of-logarithmic-cosmic-evolution-equations?noredirect=1#comment1637242_732030

Comment: Right, I did ammend it into a single post. Any advice how I can get my privileges back? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I've found a link to my own question, but in contradiction to what this poster claims, I do have positive posts out-of ten. ~

Comment: "You are currently blocked from posting further questions by the automatic question rate limiting, whose different forms I also discuss in this answer. There is nothing any user or moderator on this site can do to ameliorate this ban, it is a fully automatic consequence of your bad question record:

Of your 10 questions, none has a positive score, only one does not have a negative score, only one is not closed, and five are deleted. The question rate limiting is the system telling you to take seriously the feedback you are getting. "

Comment: @ACuriousMind yeah I figure some posts were deleted (hence the qualifier "superficially")

Comment: In any event, the universal remedy to bans is patience and extra care before posting.

Comment: as to your Logarithmic Cosmic evolution post, it is *waaaaaay* too long.  Next, "what's the hype" is not a good question for this site since one cannot answer it using physics principle.  As written it is an opinion-based question and will likely be closed.  Alternatively, you are basically asking the reader to check your work (thus susceptible to closure for this reason also). Yet again alternatively you are asking to referee your personal theory, which again is a reason for closure.

Comment: This system is very difficult thank you all.

Comment: [My most downvoted post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13635/247642) is about... *downvoting* (even though since then it received a few upvotes).