# Banned because 1 question was considered not mainstream?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen, non-mainstream-physics

The only indication that I got was that someone considered this not to be mainstream physics. They don't explain why or what I could edit to improve my post. Furthermore, this *is* a legitimate physics question because I have been working on it with a physicist in real life. In any case, I am now banned from making new posts, despite the fact that I only *have* 2 posts (now 1). So, this kind of moderation is effectively a trial, judgement, and execution with no possibility for appeal, improvement, or education. I don't understand how this approach edifies anyone whatsoever. What kind of community just murders people on sight without warning or explanation?

This is the message that I get when I try to ask a new question: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from your account...Please do not create a new account. **Instead, work on improving your existing questions by editing them to comply with the site's guidelines and address any feedback you've received.**

I only have 1 question on my account and I haven't received any feedback! This is not community improvement; this is ostracism. How can you learn if you can't ask questions? How can you ask good questions if you don't have feedback? In all seriousness, what option do I have but to make a new account?

Here is the question:

[Is it possible to show that gravity emerges from cosmic expansion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731568/)

In this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11658 the authors discard unitarity in favor of isometry for the time evolution of quantum systems. In this alteration, they are able to show how time is a quantum error correcting code.

Furthermore, in this paper, since the motivation toward isometry is also directly linked to the expansion of space, it is clear that in this framework, this expansion is responsible for the creation of new information which is isometrically mapped to information in the past. Thus, the expansion of space is a mechanism for the creation of quantum information that encodes the flow of time. Therefore, it seems intuitive to me that spacetime curvature may arise from the regional differences in the rate of expansion. Since energy densities are known to cause spacetime curvature, I am wondering if the expansion of the universe is a default state from which energy densities necessarily depart in their expansion?

Are energy densities regions of spacetime that cannot expand at the same background rate as empty space and, therefore, do not produce as much information change as empty space does in its expansion?

Comment: Re *"I am now banned from making new posts, despite the fact that I only have 2 posts"*: There [are also deleted posts](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14213/the-physics-stack-exchange-site-doesnt-care-about-new-members).

Answer (score 9):

I closed your question as non-mainstream because the core of your question is about this:

> Thus, the expansion of space is a mechanism for the creation of quantum information that encodes the flow of time. Therefore, it seems intuitive to me that spacetime curvature may arise from the regional differences in the rate of expansion.

which is not really supported by the text of the paper you refer to, hence a personal theory (or "intuition") that you're asking us to evaluate.

As for you being unable to ask questions: No user is blocked (temporarily or permanently) from posting on our site just because of a single question.

You, however, are subject to the automated question block due to excessively many deleted questions, see also [this meta answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9699/50583): The problem is not the question that is still visible nor only the one that got closed as non-mainstream, but that you have altogether now **ten** deleted questions and only one non-deleted question. Deleting a question does not erase it when the system evaluates the quality of your question record, on the contrary, deleted questions are weighed negatively just as closed questions are.

Lastly, please note that "making a new account" is **not** an option here: As discussed in [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/263383), sockpuppets on Stack Exchange sites are not allowed to circumvent system restrictions, such as asking questions from one account while the other is restricted from doing so. Users found in violation of this are likely to have their secondary accounts deleted and their main account suspended.

Comment: "on the contrary, deleted questions are weighed negatively just as closed questions are." Well this is news to me.  "Delete" doesn't actually mean delete on stackexchange. I understand your objections but you could've asked for a rephrase. Since my account is irreparably damaged I will make a new account and post the revised question in a little while.

Comment: @Asklepian Closing the question *is* me asking for a rephrasing of it: You're not supposed to delete closed questions but to *edit* them - edits automatically enqueue questions for review and questions will be reopened if the close reason no longer applies.  You should be able to undelete any deleted question and edit it. Please do **not** make a new account (see the last paragraph I just added).

Comment: Fine, I'll try it this way but my other deleted questions are still weighing me down and I have no interest in them anymore. So, I can't get around those questions. In the future, if you do close a question (implicitly asking for a rephrase), make sure to communicate which parts needed rephrasing. I was completely in the dark about all of this.

Comment: One more thing, the sentence "Thus, the expansion of space is a mechanism for the creation of quantum information that encodes the flow of time." is implied by the paper. Quantum error correction is a scheme where a small message made from quantum states is redundantly encoded inside a bigger system, thus the link to cosmic expansion. I *can* change the 2nd sentence removing intuition from my reasoning, would this suffice?

Comment: @Asklepian The paper only discusses that the expansion of space is well-modelled by a certain kind of non-unitary time evolution. You seem to think the paper implies something much father-reaching, but it is not clear to me what exactly since you don't explain your reasoning. Removing "intuitive" does nothing: You need to explain *why* you think your claim about curvature should follow.

Comment: If you have two connected regions of space, each expanding at different rates, does curvature not emerge? Does an observer traveling from one region to the other along a geodesic not experience an apparently curved path?

Comment: Compared to the multitude of garbage questions and answers that get posted every day here, this stuff seems downright Nobel prize worthy. Looks like hypocrisy to me.