# The Physics Stack Exchange site doesn't care about new members

Tags: discussion, post-ban

In [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14211/), I detail how my account has been effectively permbanned. The ultimate reason is a lot of deleted questions that I realized were irrelevant and became disinterested in.

When I joined this site, I assumed it was a forum like any other, where "delete" meant delete. Apparently, however, delete just destroys your ability to participate on the site. I have no way to remedy these deleted posts and the reality is, when I was doing all the posting and deleting, I was new and I had no idea that I was permanently ruining this account.

In every community I've ever been a part of, new members are granted more freedoms to screw up because, definitionally, they're new. This community doesn't do that.

Short of creating a new account, which I've been told would amount to a circumvention of system restrictions, I have no way of continuing to participate on the physics Stack Exchange website. I've only been active in the last two months and already I am fully ostracized.

You should allow new members to reset their reputation if they fall into this trap. I would've posted *very* differently if I had known how utterly different the rules are on this website.

I don't know what to do. I have no way to fix this account and making a new one is apparently worse than deleting posts (which is apparently the worst thing ever).

Since I have been permanently banned from the Physics Stack Exchange for no reason other than deleting my own posts and with absolutely no recourse, this is likely my last post and I would simply like to tell all of you that, in my experience, you have no consideration, respect, interest in, or dignity for new members on your forum.

Comment: You have not been "effectively permabanned". If you read the post about the automated question block I link in my answer to your other post, the block is **not**, in most cases, permanent - the duration increases for repeated blocks, but the first few instances of the block are usually only for hours or days. In fact, your account is not currently blocked from posting questions, i.e. the block has already expired.

Comment: Point taken. However, deleting posts shouldn't affect a user's reputation. If anything, deleting a post is a good sign of learning. Also, I replied to your question about how curvature arises and you didn't open the post or explain why my reply wasn't sufficient.

Comment: Beware that deleting questions on Meta can also affect your ability to post on Meta. I was in the middle of writing an answer about how good-faith users (like you, apparently) will generally respond differently to these posting restrictions than bad-faith users. However, your deletion has probably erased my draft answer, and I don’t expect I’ll have any time later to rewrite it.

Comment: I'll just have to get into the habit of not deleting things on here, however stupid the idea seems later. Sorry for erasing your draft.

Comment: Re *"deleting a post is a good sign of learning"*: But this is not a (personal) help desk system or ticket system. Posts are supposed to be valuable to future readers. It [isn't a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828), either.

Comment: You can [see your own deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416125/need-help-improving-my-question-to-remove-the-question-ban#comment895735_416125), and thus you have an option to undelete them. [Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/374184#374184). There is also a meta post with the corresponding path to follow in the user interface, but I couldn't immediately locate it.

Comment: The [general mother-meta thread on deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) has a section that clearly lays out how to get a list of your deleted questions.

Comment: [Near](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/) *"Can I see a list of my deleted posts, or find links to them?"*. There is also [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192878/change-no-deleted-recent-answers-questions-to-no-recently-deleted-answers-que/343366#343366).

Comment: A new member who cared about StackExchange would do the Tour, scan/use the Help sections, and lurk around to see how it works. You seem to be mostly upset that StackExchange does not work the way you _assumed_ it does. So, you now know better, lets move forward!

Comment: A more constructive approach is not to post “stupid ideas” so these posts do not rapidly become “irrelevant”.  It is difficult to believe that such post will of interest to the community when you yourself admit rapidly loosing interest in them.