Is there a website on the internet that allows people to ask physics questions so they can learn physics?
I've been banned from posting on physics stack exchange. All I've ever attempted to do on this account is ask simple questions to get a physicist's perspective and learn more. However, that kind of behavior is obviously discouraged here. So, where should I go to ask physics questions from knowledgeable people?

Note that deleting your questions makes it harder, rather than easier, for you to regain your asking privilege; see e.g. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/44126.

"Is there a website on the internet that allows people to ask physics questions so they can learn physics?" Yes.

See also: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/banned-because-1-question-was-considered-not-mainstream
