# Why I cannot ask question?

Tags: support, questions

I cannot post a question anymore! What can I do to solve this problem? I think somebody did not like my questions and finally, a m... f... kills me. I do not have a lot of time. What can I do?

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9641/520 More or less a duplicate even if all the details don't quite line up.

Comment: Guidance on the mother meta: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). Note in particular that deleted posts count against you (as does deletion itself); your public profile does not show any negative-score or closed questions, which probably means that you have multiple deleted posts that are causing the problem.

Comment: When will it be OK?